# How to compare genetic profiles or vcf files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have hundreds of vcf file where each vcf file contains genome profile for a tissue.
A portion of the vcf file is as follows:

[image: VCF file/dataframe]

I can read each vcf file into a dataframe. So it would be hundreds of dataframes. Each vcf file/dataframe contains hundreds of columns and 40/50 thousands rows.
I want to see the difference in ALT column for each profile (vcf files/ dataframes) on CHROM, POS, ID and REF columns.
What would be the best way to compare these dataframes/vcf files to see any similarity on ALT column?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you've somewhat elaborated your data.
Maybe first: As far as I am aware, different entities have different genetics (regarding to number of chromosomes for example), so maybe you can elaborate on how you want to use that data?
Second: Please elaborate on your target, are you trying to classify samples from this data into categories; e.g. are you trying to predict that this genetic profile belongs to a dog, or even to a specific race of dog?

Comment: maybe it's better to ask this over at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/